# Total expectation with conditional though examples

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

if I have two r.v. X,Y. Are the following correct? If so, I'd love to know why.

1. $\mathbb{E}[Y|Y] = Y  $ ? (if Y is given, does that mean that its expected value becomes just the scalar it has become?)
2. $\mathbb{E}[X+Y|Y] = Y+ \mathbb{E}[X|Y] $ (linearity of a scalar since Y is given?)
3. $\mathbb{E}[(X-d)\cdot(Y-r)|Y] = (Y-r)\cdot\mathbb{E}[(X-d)|Y]  $ , where r and d are scalars..

Thanks

Comment: Unless you show some work we won't know how you have defined conditional expectations and what results we are allowed to use. All three facts follow immediately from basic properties of conditional expectations found in text books.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be random variables (on the same probability space) and let $X$ have finite expectation.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a Borel measurable function.

Then  $f(Y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ if: $$\mathbb EX\mathbf1_B(Y)=\mathbb Ef(Y)\mathbf1_B(Y)\text{ for every Borel set }B\tag1$$

This is a *sufficient* condition and from $(1)$ it can be deduced that also:$$\mathbb EXg(Y)=\mathbb Ef(Y)g(Y)\text{ for every suitable function }g\tag2$$

Here "suitable" stands for Borel measurable and such that $g(Y)$ has finite expectation.

---

In the sequel of this answer $f(Y)$ stands for $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ so that $(1)$ and $(2)$ both are valid.

1) is correct. For this observe that  $(1)$ is a true statement if $f=\mathsf{id}_\mathbb R$ and $X=Y$.

2) is correct. For this observe that: $$\mathbb E[X+Y]\mathbf1_B(Y)=\mathbb EX\mathbf1_B(Y)+\mathbb EY\mathbf1_B(Y)=\mathbb Ef(X)\mathbf1_B(Y)+\mathbb EY\mathbf1_B(Y)=\mathbb E[f(Y)+Y]\mathbf1_B(Y)$$

3) is correct if $Y$ has finite expectation.

It is easy to deduce that $\mathbb E[X-d\mid Y]=f(Y)-d$ and applying $(2)$ on the function $g$ prescribed by $y\mapsto y-r$ we find that:$$\mathbb E[(X-d)(Y-r)\mid Y]=(f(Y)-d)(Y-r)$$